# pip/easy_install -U rosinstall problem

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am installing Diamondback afresh on Ubuntu10.04 using repository deb packages. The steps are followed as given in wiki.
By default rosinstall is not setup. I am stuck while following the steps as in http://ros.org/wiki/rosinstall .
I am behind a proxy for which http_proxy and https_proxy is defined.

Following is the output on console:

Searching for rosinstall

Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/rosinstall/

Download error: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!

This repeats couple of times. Is this issue related to proxy??? I do not face any problem when having a direct internet connnection.

Also installation of package ros-diamondback-ros-release deb ver:0.1.14-s131s503298 do not help.

I had also tried using pip. Following is the output of pip log.

```
  Downloading/unpacking rosinstall
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/rosinstall
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/rosinstall: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/rosinstall when looking for download links for rosinstall
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for rosinstall
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Cannot find requirement rosinstall, nor fetch index URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip.py", line 252, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip.py", line 408, in run
    requirement_set.install_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip.py", line 1750, in install_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip.py", line 996, in find_requirement
    url_name = self._find_url_name(Link(self.index_urls[0]), url_name, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip.py", line 1073, in _find_url_name
    raise DistributionNotFound('Cannot find requirement %s, nor fetch index URL %s' % (req, index_url))
DistributionNotFound: Cannot find requirement rosinstall, nor fetch index URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
```

---

Thanks
prince

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12851/pip/easy_install--u-rosinstall-problem/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like easy_install obey's a environment variable to setup proxys. [blog post](http://evadeflow.com/2010/09/easy_install-through-a-proxy-server/)

You can also use pip the replacement for easy_install which has a --proxy argument [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/pip.1.html)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-02-22**:
I did set http_proxy, https_proxy. It did not worked and I end up copying packages from other machine. Maybe something is broken here or i might had made some silly mistake in exporting http_proxy. I believe we shall close this question.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-02-29**:
It still do not works :( I can go to webpage http://pypi.python.org/simple/rosinstall/ and download one of rosinstall pkgs. What next shall i do? Readme file is not helpful enough.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-03-01**:
This is a problem for pip/easy_install community.  I suggest that you ask this problem on their forums.